# How does 8259A interrupt controller deal with interrupts while servicing one already?

Tags: x86, operating-system, interrupt-handling

I am reading the ["Intel 8259A" document](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2005/readings/hardware/8259A.pdf), and there is a paragraph which I am unable to fully understand (end of page 7):

> When the 8259A PIC receives an interrupt, INT becomes active and an interrupt acknowledge cycle is started. If a higher priority interrupt occurs between the two INTA pulses, the INT line goes inactive immediately after the second INTA pulse. After an unspecified amount of time the INT line is activated again to signify the higher priority interrupt waiting for service. This inactive time is not specified and can vary between parts. The designer should be aware of this consideration when designing a system which uses the 8259A. It is recommended that proper asynchronous design techniques be followed.

I understand that after first INTA (interrupt acknowledged initially) and before second INTA (CPU wants the 8-bit interrupt vector), if a higher priority interrupt line is "activated" (I am no electronic engineer), the INT line to CPU is deactivated and re-activated again after unspecified period of time.

What I don't understand is the following:

1. What are the implications of the behavior in question to me as a bare-bones (OS kernel) developer?
2. The "asynchronous design techniques" mentioned - are these HARDWARE design techniques, or allusions to people writing kernels? It seems to me there is not much I can do if an interrupt arrives between two INTA pulses - this is all happening on a level I really cannot control as a kernel developer, can I?

Comment: You, and your drivers/kernel, HAVE to handle this correctly, one way or another.

Comment: Thank you Martin. Just to point out, handling this incorrectly was never part of my design blueprints ;-) And we're back to square one, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to Question 1:

The only difference between a higher priority interrupt occurring *after* the INTA pulses and it occurring *between* the INTA pulses is in *when* the CPU is notified of the higher-priority pending interrupt. There will be a delay of zero or more cycles in the latter case. This could possibly affect timing-critical code, since a hardware device could withdraw its interrupt signal before it gets acknowledged by the CPU, resulting in a spurious interrupt (see the paragraph before the quoted text on p7).

Comment: Thank you, just wanted to let you know that it now has been a while I've been working on this, and otherwise would probably upvote and verify your answer. Alas, very little is in my head on 8259A right now, but hoping that this meanwhile benefits someone else, as is the custom here.

Comment: No worries. I've been working on an emulation for this chip, so it's pretty fresh in my head. I figured it might be useful to someone else here also.